# $view->total_rows is wrong (sort of), I want "Items to display"

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

The "`total_rows`" property of my view returns the total rows (22), but not the number of items I have set the view to display (5) (through the Web UI *Block*->*Basic Settings*).

How can I get this in a proper way without relying on (the possibly soon to be deprecated "`result`" property?

for now Im using 
`$totalRows = min($view->total_rows, count($view->result));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always available as:

`$view->display['your_display']->display_options['items_per_page']`

where `your_display` is replaced by the views display you are using (e.g. `page_1`, `block_1`, etc). This is available at all stages of building process.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$view->pager["items_per_page"]` fit your needs?  I am not 100% sure when this is available, but I am using it in a `hook_views_pre_build()` in a custom module.

Comment: This only works if you are using a pager. If you are limiting the number of rows in the view but NOT using a pager, this parameter will not be set.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The custom module I mentioned was mucking around with this value to implement a "results per page" feature for a paged view.

Answer (score 0):

By default the the result is rendered for the "default" display. If you want it for a particular display then you can use

```
$view = views_get_view('MY_VIEW_NAME');    

$view->set_display('MY_DISPLAY'); // like 'block_1'    

$view->render();   

print sizeof($view->result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution that allows to display the total results (works with and without a pager) and also, the number of results on a current page (for example, on page 2 of 10): http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/views-show-showing-x-x-x

Be warned that this solution doesn't work for block type display, only for a page.