# Display number of rows in a Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

How can I display the total number of rows shown in a Drupal view as well as the number of rows out of the total currently being shown?

`print $GLOBALS['current_view']->total_rows;`  does not work

Comment: What does it mean "in a Drupal view"? Where does this code need to fire?

Comment: It should give the total number of rows in the view as well as the total number of rows currently being displayed

Answer (score 0):

This question might be of help

[$view->total_rows is wrong (sort of), I want "Items to display"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975160/view-total-rows-is-wrong-sort-of-i-want-items-to-display)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $view = views_get_view('MY_VIEW_NAME');

  $view->set_display('MY_DISPLAY'); // like 'block_1'

  $view->render();

  print sizeof($view->result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print sizeof($view->result);
```

does not work, because it returns the number of rows, not the number of total results. So if you have a pager, this doesn't work. You'll need

```
print $view->total_rows;
```

Another, even better solution would be to implement hook_views_pre_render()

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'MY_VIEW') {
     $view->set_title(t('Search (@count results)', array('@count' => $view->total_rows > 0 ? $view->total_rows : 'No')));
   }
}
```